# Basic Authentication with Spring Boot

Tags: basic-authentication, spring-boot

I am developing a small app with spring-boot and angularjs. The idea is that the backend of the application expose some services, and the frontend consume these services. I am trying to setup basic authentication

This is my pom.xml

```
<!-- Web Server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- End Web Server -->

<!-- Spring Security -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- End Spring Security -->
```

both are in the same version 1.1.1.RELEASE. My WebSecurityConfig

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http
                .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

This is not working. Seems that the user and password are not set in memory.

When spring boot runs, it creates a default password, here is what appear in the console

```
AuthenticationManagerConfiguration : 

Using default security password: xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And the application work with that password.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried this form? curl --user name:password http://localhost:8080

Comment: @Steve thank you for your comment. I tried and it didn't work. What I am trying also is to Basic access authentication to the application with the browser.

Comment: Through the browser are you being presented with a login dialogue? Or is it going straight to the error?

Comment: @Steve In the browser I get the login dialogue. Sorry was my bad, I thought that in the class "WebSecurityConfig" I was setting "user" and "password" literally, but actually it was printing the password in the console, with that password work. I will try to figure out how to set a password. Thank you.

Comment: That config sets up in memory authentication for a user called "user" with a password "password". If you want to store users somewhere else (highly likely), then you will need to configure your own implementation of `UserDetailsService` which validates credentials against a database or LDAP.

Answer (score 6):

You can override the default user name (default value = user) and the password that is generated on the fly, by setting below properties in your `application.properties` file:

```
security.user.name=user # Default user name.
security.user.password= # Password for the default user name. A random password is logged on startup by default.
```

In order to register more than one user, you would need to build our own `AuthenticationManager` configuration.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this problem too, with an OAuth2 application. In the Authorization Server Config, I was using what turned out to be the *global* AuthenticationManager.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }
}
```

But the AuthenticationManager I built is only scoped to the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Instead of Overriding the configure method, I used this configureGlobal method and then everything fell into place, with no warnings or NullReferenceExceptions

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your configur(HttpSecurity http) method, your last setup says `.anyRequest().authenticated()`, so it will require that users be authenticated for all requests.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Try the following.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .anonymous()
            .disable();
}
```

Comment: @PatricGimard thank you for your answer. It didn't work, it has the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This way worked, first I changed dependencies in the pom.xml

```
<!-- Web Server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- End Web Server -->

<!-- Spring Security -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- End Spring Security -->
```

Then I changed the class WebSecurityConfig

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return new AuthenticationManagerBuilder(new NopPostProcessor())
                       .inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
                       .and().and().build();
    }

    private static class NopPostProcessor implements ObjectPostProcessor {
        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public Object postProcess(Object object) {
            return object;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: this solution caused some very strange `java.lang.NullPointerException: null` and also it doesn't really make it clear if there is still a user being created that could cause a security breach

Comment: @cahen thank you for your feedback I will not mark as the correct answer then.